# Detecting missing __declspec(dllimport) in access to exported globals across dll boundaries

Tags: c, windows, winapi, dll, linker

I'm looking for solutions to a fun new wrinkle in Windows support for the PostgreSQL project.

When plugin DLLs are loaded into the main executable with a `LoadLibrary` call they expect the dynamic linker to resolve references to functions *and global variables* exposed by `postgres.exe`.

It's easy to forget to put a `__declspec(dllimport)` annotation, or rather, the `PGDLLIMPORT` macro that expands to it, on an `extern` that's accessed via a DLL, since almost all PostgreSQL development and testing happens on Linux and OS X, where none of this stuff applies.

The project relies on automated testing to detect when a `__declspec(dllimport)` is missing on a function, as this causes linker errors. Until yesterday the assumption was that the same was true for global variables, but it isn't; it turns out that dynamic linkage *succeeds silently, producing a garbage result*.

So - I'm looking for advice on how to *detect* and *prevent* such illegal accesses, where a global is not `__declspec(dllimport)`'ed.

This is complicated by the fact that on Windows, PostgreSQL's build system generates `.def` files that just export everything. (Not my doing, but I can't change it, yes, I know). This means that even if there's no `PGDLLIMPORT` marking the site `__declspec(dllexport)` during building of the main executable, the symbol is still exported.

Ideas? Is there any way to get the linker to throw a runtime error when an `extern` global is defined in another module and the `extern` isn't properly `__declspec(dllimport)` annotated?

If the project stopped generating .def files and instead used `PGDLLIMPORT` annotations that expand to `__declspec(dllexport)` when compiling the .exe, and `__declspec(dllimport)` when compiling plugins that use the exe's API, would that produce linker errors when a symbol isn't annotated properly? Is there any alternative to that?

I'm currently looking for more info and I'm going to be writing a few test programs to try to test ideas, but I'm far from an expert on Windows development and I'm looking for an authoritative "the right way to do it" if possible.

Comment: You want to make it *easier* for somebody to export global variables???  Let them suffer!  And outlaw the practice as a project guideline.  The alternatives are just too simple and superior.

Comment: @HansPassant I completely agree, but unfortunately am not presently in a position to change the practice, only fix any resulting bugs.

Comment: Posted follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593281/generating-correct-def-files-to-export-non-static-functions-and-globals

Comment: Also, useful article (for the Windows-specific bits): http://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html

Comment: @CraigRinger So, will it be trilogy? Or your problem can be considered fully solved?

Comment: @qwm I hope to find out for sure today ;-) but with a way to identify the symbol types in objdump output it looks good. I hugely appreciate your time and assistance, as I'm out of my depth with more than the simplest Windows-specific compiler/linker issues, and would've spent a *lot* more time staring at half-understood diassemblies and flailing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to make it clear in `.def` file to linker that you export data, not code:

```
EXPORTS
   i1 DATA
   i2 DATA
```

or not use `.def` at all. It takes precedence and defaults exported symbol to `code`.

Let's look what happens when you link your plugin to such malformed `.lib` file. And assume you declare:

```
   int __declspec(dllimport) i1;
   extern int i2;
```

This means your `.obj` file will have external dependencies `__imp__i1` and `_i2`. And while the first one will point to the real imported symbol, `jmp`-stub

```
   jmp [addr]  ; FF 25 xx xx xx xx
```

will be generated for the second one ('cause it considered to be the code symbol) which is meant to fix difference between two kinds of call:

```
   call [addr] ; FF 15 xx xx xx xx
   call addr   ; E8 xx xx xx xx
```

Thus, your `i2` will actually point to code section address of jmp-stub, so its value gonna be`0x????25ff`.

Comment: Thankyou. I'll take a look at the generated def files to verify they're marking the exports correctly. This is a plausible explanation for the observed behaviour. I'd rather the "not use a .def file at all" approach, personally, but unfortunately that's not an option for non-technical reasons at present. I'll follow up (it will take me a while) with confirmation about whether the defs contain `DATA` annotations or nt.

Comment: @gwm Looks like the .def generator (which loops over `dumpbin` output) is not annotating exported globals with `DATA`. So that needs fixing, at least. I'll see what's involved and comment on how that goes.

Comment: @CraigRinger any progress?

Comment: @qvm In Australia, busy sleeping ;-) . Should have time to test patching the def generator today.

Comment: @qvm The def generator code uses dumpbin output, and there doesn't seem to be a good way to get the symbol type (data, function) from the dumpbin output. Fun. So that becomes a separate project. I'm convinced by this explanation, though. Thankyou _very_ much for taking the time to introduce me to a new and kind of gruesome twist to the Windows Linking Quirks saga.

Comment: @qvm Found a v.useful link explaining some of the issues, though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa271769(v=vs.60).aspx - particularly that an extra layer of indirection is assumed on extern vars w/o `__declspec(dllimport)`. And confirmed symbols default to code if DATA or CONSTANT isn't specified - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyx1zcd3.aspx . Didn't find any reference to confirm the DEF file overrides __declspec annotations though, or in fact anything that explains the ordering/precedence/merging rules for multiple specifications except around handling of `NONAME`.

Comment: `Didn't find any reference to confirm the DEF file overrides __declspec annotations though` - you may try to confirm it by testing on a toy project. I didn't read any articles stating that, just parsed compiler/linker output