# Generating correct .DEF files to export non-static functions AND GLOBALS

Tags: c, windows, linker, dllexport, dumpbin

Following on from [a question about detecting bad linkage to globals across dll boudaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568431/detecting-missing-declspecdllimport-in-access-to-exported-globals-across-dll), it turns out that I need to modify a .DEF file generator tool used by the PostgreSQL project so that it correctly emits `DATA` tags for .DEF entries for global variables.

### Problem

I can't seem to find a way, using Microsoft's tools, to get a symbol table listing that differentiates between global variables and functions, and that includes globals that aren't initialized at their definition site.

Ideas?

### Broken current approach

The tool loops over `dumpbin /symbols` output to generate the .DEF file. Unlike `nm`, which  I'm used to, `dumpbin /symbols` does not appear to emit an entry for each symbol to indicate the symbol type - function, initialized variable, uninitialized variable. It only shows whether the symbol is locally defined or not.

With each `dumpbin` output line followed by the corresponding definition in the `.c` file, we have first an initialized global:

```
00B 00000000 SECT3  notype       External     | _DefaultXactIsoLevel
int         DefaultXactIsoLevel = XACT_READ_COMMITTED;
```

vs a function with non-static linkage:

```
022 00000030 SECT5  notype ()    External     | _IsAbortedTransactionBlockState
bool IsAbortedTransactionBlockState(void) {...}
```

... and for bonus fun, un-initialized globals appear to be shown as `UNDEF`, just like references to symbols from other compilation units, e.g:

```
007 00000004 UNDEF  notype       External     | _XactIsoLevel
int         XactIsoLevel;
```

even though this is pre-declared in the header during compilation (with project specific macro hand expanded for readability) as:

```
extern __declspec(dllexport) int XactIsoLevel;
```

So... it looks like `dumpbin` output doesn't contain enough information to generate a correct `.DEF` file.

Right now `gendefs.pl` is merrily spitting out a `.DEF` file that omits globals that aren't initialized, and declares everything else as code (by failing to specify `CONSTANT` or `DATA` in the .DEF). For something so broken, it's worked remarkably well.

### Fixing it

To produce correct .DEF files, I need a way to determine which symbols are variables.

I looked at using `cl.exe`'s `/Fm` option, but it's just a passthrough to the linker's `/MAP` option, and does nothing when you're just generating an object file, not linking it.

I could use a symbol dump tool that produces more useful information like gcc's `nm.exe`, but that adds extra tool dependencies and seems fragile.

At this point I am not able to simply annotate every exported function with `PGDLLIMPORT` (the `__declspec(dllimport)` / `__declspec(dllexport)` macro used by the project) and stop using a DEF file.

Even if I could I need to find an approach that will cause clear linker errors when `PGDLLIMPORT` is omitted on an exposed variable.

So. Windows linker/compiler experts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I must say I was wrong saying that microsoft tools doesn't use symbol type field at all.

**1).** `cl` doesn't use it to differentiate actual type info, but it stores information that you need:

- `0x20` means function
- `0x00` means not a function

[PE/COFF specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/gg463125), p. 46-47.

You may search for presence/abscence of `()` after symbol type (`notype` in your case) in `dumpbin`'s output to find whether it is `code` or `data`.

**2).** Also, `cl` generates in `obj` files special section for linker which include `export` switch for every `__declspec(dllexport)` symbol in the form `/export:symbol[,type]`.

**3).** And last, you can specify 'C++' external linkage and get symbols' types because of mangling.

Comment: Ah, I'm blind re `()`. Thankyou very much, that might well be enoubh to go on. (Unfortunately I can't use the export switch output because it's only useful for explicit exports, and the whole issue here is that project policy currently prevents me from just adding exports everywhere.)

Comment: It's okay. Just use 1st solution. Other two I provided for the sake of completeness only.

Answer (score 2):

I just add to the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21598892/4949209).
`dumpbin` has a specific option, namely `/headers`, that clearly points out the *Type* as **code** or **data**, together with a list of other attributes.